# MalformedURLException in RMI Naming.rebind() in ArchLinux/CentOS

Tags: java, linux, exception, rmi

I have two servers with which I am using RMI to connect to, AServer and BServer.

AServer's relevent code is:

```
int port = Integer.parseInt("1234");
String url = "rmi://localhost:" + port + "/Aclass";
System.out.println("binding " + url);
Naming.rebind(url, new AClass());
```

BServer's relevent code is:

```
int port = Integer.parseInt("1234");
String url = "//localhost:" + port + "/Bclass";
System.out.println("binding " + url);
Naming.rebind(url, new BClass());
```

On ArchLinux/CentOS, when I run the following command for AServer:

```
 java -cp ".:./protobuf.jar" -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=protobuf.jar -Djava.security.policy=policy AServer
```

and the corresponding code for BServer:

```
 java -cp ".:./protobuf.jar" -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=protobuf.jar -Djava.security.policy=policy BServer
```

Whereas for AServer the console prints:

```
 binding rmi://localhost:1234/AServer
 server rmi://localhost:1234/AServer is running...
```

BServer prints:

```
binding rmi://localhost:1234/BServer
Place server failed:Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: protobuf.jar
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: protobuf.jar
     at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:247)
     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:379)
     at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
     at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
     at BServer.main(BServer.java:31)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: protobuf.jar
     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
     at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.pathToURLs(LoaderHandler.java:770)
     at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.getDefaultCodebaseURLs(LoaderHandler.java:141)
     at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:170)
     at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
```

Which shows that the error must be in the Name.rebind() command but I'm stumped because the URL is wellformed as far as I know.

Both servers work fine in Mac OS running with command:
     java -cp ".:./protobuf.jar" -Djava.security.policy=policy AServer

They work perfectly as I want them to, however in ArchLinux/CentOS I need to add the

-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=... or I get a NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of a codebase specification are URLs, not filenames. You haven't specified either a protocol or an absolute path.

It won't work anyway. A `java.rmi.server.codebase` must be expressed in a form that is intelligible to the peer. Merely repeating the a classpath element is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what do you mean by you haven't specified either a protocol or an absolute path."?

And are you saying that I shouldn't use java.rmi.server.codebase at all then? In that case I get a NoClassDefFoundError..?

Comment: What I mean by 'you haven't specified either a protocol or an absolute path' is that the specification `-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=protobuf.jar` contains neither a protocol or an absolute path. I doubt that you really need to use the codebase feature, certainly not at a beginner stage.

Comment: So how would you go about fixing this? 
I'm pretty sure we don't need the codebase part...

Comment: So remove it, and make sure that the Registry and the client have that .jar file on their CLASSPATH.

Comment: The servers and the client all have the reference to the same .jar file but still has the same error...

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` actually means a packaging error. The .class file found doesn't contain the expected class, probably because the package and the directory don't agree, or the actual filename. Post the stack trace, and a `jar -tvf` listing of the .jar file. Edit them into your question.